# array grouping or sorting is not working

Tags: php, arrays

Here this is my array.

```
 Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 50.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-07-18
            )  
        [1] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 0.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-07-17
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 60.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-07-18
            )
    )
```

I am trying to sort or grouping to array according to date.transaction date should be one means no duplicate entry of transaction in array.

I want new array as follows

```
Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amt] => 110.00
                    [transaction_date] => 2015-07-18
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [amt] => 0.00
                    [transaction_date] => 2015-07-17
                )            

        )
```

2015-07-18 this date appears 2 times in array with 2 different amount amount should added as per repetition. amount should be 110

```
$temp=0;
        $ctr=0;            
        for($i=0;$i<count($new_data);$i++)
        {
            $temp=$new_data[$i]['transaction_date'];

            for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++)
            {
                if($temp==$new_data[$j]['transaction_date'])
                {                  
                   $newarray[][$new_data[$j]['transaction_date']]=++$ctr;

                }

            }
            $ctr=0;
        }            
       print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `foreach` as

```
$result = array();
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['transaction_date'];
    if (isset($result[$hash])) {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] += $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] = $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/408859)